# Understanding a specific method for applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem and its implications with regard to the lower bound of a solution

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Observation:**

Consider the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) applied to this problem of $n$ remainders where each $p_i$ is a prime:

$$x \equiv r_1 \pmod {p_1}$$
$$x \equiv r_2 \pmod {p_2}$$
$$\dots$$
$$x \equiv r_n \pmod {p_n}$$

It occurs to me that any solution can be represented by this form where each $0 \le a_i < p_i$ is an integer:

$$r_1 + a_2(p_1) + a_3(p_1p_2) + a_4(p_1p_2p_3) + \dots + a_n(p_1p_2\dots p_{n-1})$$

Here's my reasoning:

(1)  $r_1 \equiv r_1 \pmod {p_1}$

(2)  The addition of any multiple of $p_1$ preserves the relation and $r_1, r_1 + p_1, r_1 + 2p_1, \dots, r_1 + (p_2-1)p_1$ forms a [complete residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) modulo $p_2$ so that there exists $0 \le a_2 < p_2$ such that $r_1 + a_2p_1 \equiv r_2 \pmod {p_2}$

(3)  The addition of any multiple of $p_1p_2$ preserves (1) and (2) and $r_1 + a_2p_1, r_1 + a_2p_1 + p_1p_2, r_1 + a_2p_1 + 2p_1p_2, \dots, r_1 + a_2p_1 + (p_3-1)p_1p_2$ forms a complete residue system modulo $p_3$ so that there exists $0 \le a_3 < p_3$ such that $r_1 + a_2p_1 + a_3p_1p_2 \equiv r_3 \pmod {p_3}$

(4)  We can repeat the same method up to $a_n$ to get the desired result.

I'm interested in this method because it provides an opportunity to establish a lower bound for a given solution.

**Question:**

Assuming that the form above is correct (I believe that it is), is it possible to determine conditions whereby each $a_i$ is nonzero?

It seems to me that this might be the case if no $r_i$ are equal.

If all $r_i$ were the same.  Then $r_1$ is itself the solution with all $a_i = 0$

Are there any other conditions that can be called out where the solution will necessarily have all $a_i$ nonzero?  I am also interested if a condition exists where $a_n$ is nonzero.

Is this an open question?

I am interested because if $a_n$ is nonzero, then $x > p_1p_2p_3\dots p_{n-1}$

---

**Addendum:** Suggested by Gerry Myerson in his comment

I was testing out different combinations using simple primes such as $3,5,7,11$.

I've made three observations.  All of them pretty trivial and not too helpful to a general condition (as far as I can see).

(1) If any 2 $r_i$ are congruent  modulo the same prime, then that can allow one $a_i=0$

For example, if:

$$x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$
$$x \equiv 8 \pmod {11}$$

(2)  If any of the $n!$ ways to construction a solution have $a_i=0$, then all of the other combinations have at least one $a_i=0$.

(3) If a solution is less than the product of any $n-1$ primes, then $a_n=0$.

None of these provide a condition that ensures that $a_n > 0$.

Comment: Why don't you look to see what happens with some small numbers, say, $n=3$, and moduli $5,6,7$ or $5,7,11$ or some such?

Comment: Great point.  I will continue to work with small numbers to see if I can see any patterns.  :-)

Comment: Are the $p_i$ assumed to be primes ? This isn't clearly said in the question as it is now

Comment: Yes, each $p_i$ is a prime.  I'll update the question. Thanks very much for calling this out.  :-)

Comment: It is natural to put $a_1=r_1$. Then in your decomposition, $a_2$ is unique because it is the remainder modulo $p_2$ of $x_2=\frac{x-r_1}{p_1}$. Similary, $a_3$ is unique because it is the remainder modulo $p_3$ of $x_3=\frac{x_2-r_2}{p_2}$. And so on. So all your $a_i$'s are uniquely defined, and then it is clear that $a_n\neq 0$ if and only if $x\geq p_1p_2(...)p_{n-1}$ (assuming $x\geq 0$).

Comment: To be clear, i am looking for a criteria (if it exists) for when $a_n \ne 0$ without looking at the value of $x$.  I'm wondering if this decision can be made based on the properties of $x$.    I am trying to set a general lower bound if possible.  If that is not possible, calling that out would help me.  If it is possible, I am looking for the properties.  :-)

Comment: I see. When you say "without looking at the values of $x$", you mean, "by looking only at the values of $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n$".

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to see if there is a relationship between $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n$ and whether $a_n$ is $0$ or not.

Comment: At the beginning of the question you wrote that “It occurs to me that any solution can be represented by this form where each $0 \le a_i < p_i$ is an integer”. But if $x$ is a solution of the system then $x+kp_1\dots p_n$ is a solution of the system for each integer $k$. So, taking into account the above [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706690/understanding-a-specific-method-for-applying-the-chinese-remainder-theorem-and-i#comment7626333_3706690) by Ewan Delanoy, I guess that exactly one solution $x$ of the system has the described representation.

Comment: From CRT, as I understand it, there is only 1 integer less than the product of all the primes $p_i$ that satisfies the congruence relations.  My question is whether an explicit condition exists relating to $r_1, r_2, \dots r_n$ where a lower bound can be found with $a_n > 0$.   Apologies if my question is unclear.  I am glad to revise it if you have thoughts on how I can make it more clear.

Comment: Yes you can do this. The reason is almost the same as the reason that all positive integers can be written as $n = a_0 + a_1 \cdot 10 + a_2 \cdot 10^2 + \cdots$.